Can we call the respective original function with parameters automatically from proxy class in C++?
I have a class and a proxy class which holds pointer to original class to call its functions in C++. I am using proxy class for logging purpose . From each function of proxy class , In addition to logging , I am calling the same function from original class , with exactly same parameters in the current function . As I have more classes and functions I am trying to find a solution to automate this . Like from each function , if I just call call() method , it should call respective original class functions with current function parameters .
With the help of template I achieved below code ,
class Original {
public:
    void function1(int a) {
        // Implementation of function1
    }

    int function2(double b) {
        // Implementation of function2
    }

    // More functions...
};

class Proxy {
private:
    Original original;

public:
    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    auto call(Func func, Args&&... args) -> decltype((original.*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return (original.*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void function1(int a) {
        //Do some condition check and logging

        call(&Original::function1, a);

        //Do some condition check and logging
    }

    void function2(double b) {
        //Do some condition check and logging

        call(&Original::function2, b);

        //Do some condition check and logging
    }

    // More functions...
};


Here again I am calling call(&Original::function2, b) from each function which is similar to calling Original.function2(b).
I wanted to reduce mentioning function name and parameters . something like just calling call() , should automatically pass the function and parameters . So that in large code base projects it will be easier. Is it possible to achieve this functionality? I am using C++ 20.

The problem is how compiler supposed to know that you want to call the same name function from Original. That is, there is no relationship between Proxy::function1 and Original::function1 from this can be known. In other words, names are just for us humans, they're actually different functions from different classes.

I don't think there is any way unless maybe if you use inheritance.

@jls28 can you please elaborate ?

@jls28 And , Proxy::function1(int a ){ // do logging ; // how will I call function1(int a) from Original ? }. The Purpose of proxy class is logging . After logging it has to call original function .

@jls28 How can I do logging for each function ?

I suggest you change your proxy to:
class Proxy {
private:
    Original original;

public:
    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    auto call(Func func, Args&&... args) -> decltype((original.*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        // Do some condition check and logging
        auto res =  (original.*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // Do some condition check and logging
    }
};

And instead of calling Proxy::function1(...) the user calls Proxy::call(&Object::function1,...). If Original gets a method added, nothing has to be changed on Proxy, there is no repetition of names of functions.

Each function will have its own condition checking and logging. Single template cannot solve this right.

@sureshkumar please edit the question to clarify the requirements. Though, if each function needs its own checkign and logging, why do you worry about +1 line that each function needs ?

I can propose another solution :
(it can work because the operator-> has
special behiavor when not returning a pointer)
class Proxy
{
private:
  Original original;

public:
 struct InnerProxy
 {
   Original * po;

  InnerProxy(Original & o) : po(&o)
  {
   // Login enter here
  }

  ~InnerProxy()
  {
   // Logging leave here
  }

   Original * operator->() {return po;}
 };

 InnerProxy operator->()
 {return InnerProxy(original);}

};


C++ at this time has no real access to names of functions at runtime, and compile-time reflection is also still incoming.
We can still follow DRY, but it will require some macros.  I dislike macros, so I'll minimize them.
#define RETURNS(...) \
  ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define INVOKE_METHOD(NAME) \
  [](auto* self, auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( self->NAME( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ) )
#define INVOKE_CONST_METHOD(NAME) \
  [](auto const* self, auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( self->NAME( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ) )

Now, INVOKE_METHOD(Foo) is a concrete C++ object that represents invoking a method named Foo on some as yet undetermined object.
#define PROXY_METHOD_R(NAME, RETTYPE) \
  RETTYPE NAME(auto&&...args) \
    BeforeLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    RETTYPE retval = INVOKE_METHOD(NAME)(&original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    AfterLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    return retval; \
  }
#define PROXY_METHOD(NAME) \
  void NAME(auto&&...args) \
    BeforeLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    INVOKE_METHOD(NAME)(&original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    AfterLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    return; \
  }
#define PROXY_CONST_METHOD_R(NAME, RETTYPE) \
  RETTYPE NAME(auto&&...args) const \
    BeforeLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    RETTYPE retval = INVOKE_CONST_METHOD(NAME)(&original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    AfterLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    return retval; \
  }
#define PROXY_CONST_METHOD(NAME) \
  void NAME(auto&&...args) const \
    BeforeLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    INVOKE_CONST_METHOD(NAME)(&original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    AfterLog( #NAME, &original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ); \
    return; \
  }

now we write our Proxy:
class Proxy {
private:
  Original original;
  template<class...Args>
  void BeforeLog( char const* method, Original const*, Args&&...args ) const;
  template<class...Args>
  void AfterLog( char const* method, Original const*, Args&&...args ) const;
public:
  PROXY_METHOD(function1)
  PROXY_METHOD(function2)

  // More functions...
};

each new proxied function is a single macro invoke.  The forwarding is not quite perfect, but probably good enough.

You can use this reflection library: https://github.com/ReflectCxx/ReflectionTemplateLibrary-CPP to achieve your goal.
Start by creating a class MyReflection inheriting rtl::access::CxxMirror and registering your functions with a string. Here’s an example in MyReflection.cpp:
#include "RTLibInterface.h" //include it in MyReflection.h file.
#include "Original.h"
using namespace rtl::builder;

MyReflection::MyReflection(): rtl::access::CxxMirror({
      Reflect().record<Original>("Original").constructor().build(),
      Reflect().record<Original>("Original").method("function1").build(&Original::function1),
      Reflect().record<Original>("Original").method("function2").build(&Original::function2),
      Reflect().record<Original>("Original").method("function3").build(&Original::function3)
    })
{ }

Next, define your proxy class:
#include "MyReflection.h"
using namespace rtl::access;

class Proxy
{
    MyReflection reflection;
    std::optional<Record> originalClass;
    Instance originalObj;

public:
    Proxy(): originalClass(reflection.getRecord("Original"))
    {
        if (originalClass) 
        {
            auto [status, obj] = originalClass->instance();
            if (status == rtl::Error::None) {
                originalObj = obj;
            }
            else { /*default constructor not registered.*/ }
        }
        else { /*class 'Original' is not registered.*/ }
    }

    template<typename...Args>
    std::any call(std::string funcStr, Args...args)
    {
        const auto& method = originalClass->getMethod(funcStr);

        if (!method.has_value() || !method->hasSignature<args...>()) {
        /*  method not registered for key 'funcStr' or the given arguments did not match.
            return empty std::any */
            return std::any();
        }

        const auto& retVal = method->on(originalObj).call(args...);
        return retVal.getReturn();
    }
};

You can now invoke Proxy::call("function2", 3.141) using the function name as a string. If needed, you can add Proxy::beforeLog and Proxy::afterLog to log every function call. Alternatively, for decoupled logging, create a separate Logger class with static functions. Register these to rtl::CxxMirror constructor in MyReflection.cpp, allowing you to call specific Logger methods for corresponding Original methods.
By following this approach, if you add a new function to class Original or class Logger, you only need to update MyReflection.cpp. The Proxy class doesn’t require recompilation. This effectively separates concerns, keeping Proxy unaware of the Original and Logger types or any other types that might be added in the future.
You can also decouple the MyReflection instance from Proxy by managing it as a singleton or with a smart pointer. This approach makes your design more flexible and helps in managing the lifetime of the MyReflection object independently.
An important note about performance and memory: CxxMirror does not use RTTI (Run-Time Type Information) and does not allocate anything on the heap (except for instances created via reflection). It creates static tables of lambdas that wrap the registered functors, which remain in memory for the application's lifetime, even after the MyReflection object is destroyed. But it ensures that the space complexity is O(1), and reflection calls are handled with O(1) time complexity.
